# How can I preserve the order I decide in divergent plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

I want to follow this order = genes_order, which I guess is modified by the "stat = identity", overriding it. I don't know how to keep it this way, without the interference of quantitative (if so, because it's not clear) order

The order

```
genes_order <- c("ABCA1","ABCG1","NR1H2","NR1H3","PPARA",
"PPARD","PPARG","RXRA","RXRB")

df_plot2$gen <- as.factor(df_plot2$gen)
df_plot2 <- as.data.frame(df_plot2)
df_plot2 <- df_plot2[order(df_plot2$gen), ]
```

The plot: as you can see the order is altered

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = df_plot2, aes(x = reorder(gen, RQ_gapdh), y = RQ_gapdh, ymin = after_scale(1), fill = Color)) +  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=Color), width=.5)+
  labs(x = "Genes", y = 2^-ddCt~ "value",
       title = "Gene expression",
       subtitles = "1 year post-intervention")+
  guides(fill = F) +
  coord_flip()+
  facet_wrap(~grup_int, labeller = labeller(grup_int = c("1" = "Olive oil", "2" = "Nuts", "3" = "Low-fat diet")))
```

[image]

This is my df

```
df_plot2 <- 
structure(list(gen = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 9L), levels = c("ABCA1", "ABCG1", "NR1H2", "NR1H3", 
"PPARA", "PPARD", "PPARG", "RXRA", "RXRB"), class = "factor"), 
    grup_int = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    time = c("3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
    "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
    "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), RQ_gapdh = c(1.019, 1.218, 1.183, 
    0.926, 1.132, 1.052, 0.936, 1.117, 0.961, 0.987, 1.182, 0.971, 
    1.008, 0.985, 0.951, 0.935, 1.149, 1.058, 0.914, 1.01, 0.952, 
    0.913, 1.134, 1.112, 0.985, 1.074, 1.135), Color = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("FALSE", 
    "TRUE"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(8L, 17L, 26L, 
9L, 18L, 27L, 5L, 14L, 23L, 4L, 13L, 22L, 1L, 10L, 19L, 2L, 11L, 
20L, 3L, 12L, 21L, 6L, 15L, 24L, 7L, 16L, 25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Set the new factors with order, before plotting: `df_plot2$gen <- factor(df_plot2$gen, levels = gene_order )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you `reorder()` your `gen` variable. Drop that and you should be fine. And if you want to reverse the order then could do so by setting `limits=rev` in `scale_x/y_discrete`.

Note: I dropped the `coord_flip` and switched the mapping on x and y instead.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df_plot2, aes(
  x = RQ_gapdh, y = gen,
  fill = Color
)) +
  geom_col(width = .5) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev) +
  labs(
    y = "Genes", x = 2^-ddCt ~ "value",
    title = "Gene expression",
    subtitles = "1 year post-intervention"
  ) +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  facet_wrap(~grup_int,
    labeller = labeller(
      grup_int = c(
        "1" = "Olive oil",
        "2" = "Nuts",
        "3" = "Low-fat diet"
      )
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: The problem here is I need to put the zero on number one, and depending on the value, if <1 go to the left and >1 go right (divergently). And adding  ymin = after_scale(1), fill = Color)) is not working with the geom_col argument (instead of geom_bar)

Comment: Aw. Now I understand what you are doing with the after_scale. Simply add it back in, but switch y for x, i.e. do `xmin = after_scale(1))`.